# jQuery Cascading drop down issue on dynamic table row in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

This is regarding an issue related to the dynamic html table row controls. I have 2 cascading dropdowns named tagId and tagName. I have successfully implemented the cascading dropdowns. But the issue is while I am adding new rows to the table dynamically, the cascading drop downs are not working any more, on child rows. But, it's working properly on the top row. Please help me to resolve this.

From PopulateTagName.jsp I am getting second dropdown values based on first dropdown value.

Code::

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <%
    
    %>
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var selected = document.getElementById("TagID").value;    
      if (selected != "Select Tag ID") {
    
     var xmlhttp;
     if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
              else {
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }  
    
       xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var doc = this.responseText;
            var ar = doc.split(',');
            var sel = document.getElementById('TagName');
            document.getElementById("TagName").options.length = 1;
            for( var i= 0; i< ar.length; i++){
                var opt = document.createElement('option');
                opt.innerHTML = ar[i];
                opt.value=ar[i];
                sel.appendChild(opt);
            }
        }
        
      };    
            xmlhttp.open("POST","PopulateTagName.jsp?TagID="+selected , true);
            xmlhttp.send(); 
        }
    }
    
     $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#addRow').click(function(){
        
                       var sno=$('#pTable tr').length;
                           trow=  "<tr><td class='sNo'>"+sno+"</td>"+
                                "<td><select name='TagID' id ='TagID' onchange='myFunction()'><option value='Select Tag ID'>Select Tag ID</option><option value='test1'>test1</option><option value='test2'>test2</option><option value='test3'>test3</option><option value='test4'>test4</option></select></td>"+
                               "<td><select name='TagName'><option value ='Select Tag Name'>Select Tag Name</option></select></td>"+
                               "<td><input name='TagValue' type='text'></td>"+                           
                              "<td><button type='button' class='rButton'>Remove</button></td></tr>";
                          $('#pTable').append(trow);
                        });
    }); 
    
    $(document).on('click', 'button.rButton', function () {
           $(this).closest('tr').remove();
           arrangeSno();
         return false;
     });
     function arrangeSno(){
       var i=0;
        $('#pTable tr').each(function() {
            $(this).find(".sNo").html(i);
            i++;
        });
     } 
     
    </script>
    <table id="pTable">     
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Serial No</td>
                <td>*Select Tag ID:</td>
                <td>Select Tag Name:</td>
                <td>Input Tag Value:</td>           
                <td><input id="addRow" type="button" value="Add"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>    
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the pre generated DOM it works with the

```
     $('#addRow').click(function(){
```

But for the newly added DOM elements it works only with the .live function rather than .on so you must write your code as

```
$(document).live('click', '#addRow', function () {
```

*Note : I can't regerate your issue on my machine but although ran into the same issue a long ago. And here's the solution. :)*

Comment: After using live, if I click on just UI, multiple rows are getting created

Comment: You might have not changed .click() to .live() but added another function suggested by me. Which is triggering 2 click events on a single click. You should just keep a single .live() and remove .click() That will remove duplicate event firing. Keep posted. If possible share updated code.